# Using 'last modified' site wide, rather than on specific page/post

Tags: wordpress

I want to show some text along the lines of 'This website was last updated on 10/11/2019' - I can find solutions to do this on individual pages and posts, but not something that queries the DB and finds the last update across the site.

I have tried to adapt some wp_query but failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by Two ways:
1: You can do it by using [This Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-last-modified-info/)
2: if you don't want to use this plugin you can edit function.php file add this code there

```
function wpb_last_updated_date( $content ) {
$u_time = get_the_time('U'); 
$u_modified_time = get_the_modified_time('U'); 
if ($u_modified_time >= $u_time + 86400) { 
$updated_date = get_the_modified_time('F jS, Y');
$updated_time = get_the_modified_time('h:i a'); 
$custom_content .= '<p class="last-updated">Last updated on '. $updated_date . ' at '. $updated_time .'</p>';  
} 

$custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpb_last_updated_date' );
```

This code checks to see if a post’s published date and last modified dates are different. If they are, then it displays last modified date before the post content.

you can add css to make it look better

```
.last-updated {
font-size: small;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #fffdd4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to do. I want to say when the blog as a whole was last updated, not a single blog post.